# Agnular passing errors from parent form to nested control which uses controlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have created location Form based on ControlValueAccessor. I have noticed when I do api call in parent component and it returns some errors related to location control which is part of parent form and the parent form see those errors, but for some reason child form doesn't see them.

organization.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="organizationForm" class="organization-form">
        ....
        <app-location-form 
            formControlName="location"
            [locationErrors]="organizationForm.get('location').errors" // <----
        ></app-location-form>
</div>
```

as you can see I am passing them via date binding, because I couldn't figure out how can I do it in some other way.

and thats how they are being displayed in child component:

location-form.component.ts

```
<form class="location-form" [formGroup]="locationForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field
    class="form-field"
    [matTooltip]="readonlyText"
    [matTooltipDisabled]="!isFormDisabled"
  >
  <mat-error *ngIf="(locationErrors?.backend?.address)[0]"> // <------
    {{ (locationErrors?.backend?.address)[0] }}             // <------
  </mat-error>                                              // <------

    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Adres"
      formControlName="address"
      [matAutocomplete]="addressAuto"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
...
</form>
```

because, the `locationForm.errors` are null although  when I go up to parent component and check value of `organizationForm.location.errors` it has expected errors assigned. I thought that ControlValueAccessor would be able to do the trick and sync errors from parent form control to child form but unfortunately it doesn't, and I don't think my solution is the way in which you should deal with it. So I am asking for some advice, how to make the errors, which have been set to control in parent form to be reflected in child form so I can read them directly from there?